# How to get labels of clicked position in Bokeh heatmap

Tags: javascript, python, visualization, bokeh

I have Bokeh heatmap. I register callback and able to get x and y coordinates of clicked position. Is there way to get x and y labels for the same positions? It seems that cb_data doesn't contain any useful information.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(xname=xname, 
                                    yname=yname, 
                                    colors=color, 
                                    alphas=alpha,
                                    means=means.flatten(),
                                    stds=stds.flatten(),))

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""alert(JSON.stringify(cb_obj));""")

p = figure(title="Plot",
           x_axis_location="above", 
           tools="pan,hover,save,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset",
           x_range=labels, y_range=list(reversed(labels)))
p.js_on_event('tap', callback)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it finally.

```
tapCallback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
var index = source.selected['1d'].indices;
xlabel = source.data.xname[index];
ylabel = source.data.yname[index];
alert(ylabel + '-' + xlabel);
""")

p.select_one(HoverTool).tooltips = [('OD:', '@yname-@xname'),('mean', '@means'),('std', '@stds'),]
p.select_one(TapTool).callback = tapCallback
```